# Can I unmarshal an InputStream?

Tags: java, http, inputstream

I make a post call to a URL and I receive a token in JSON format.
I need to unmarshal the inpustream to a DTO token object.

I am thinking something like this:

```
public String getToken(URL auth) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) auth.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    TokenDTO reply = new TokenDTO();
    
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
    
    try {
     JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TokenDTO.class);
     Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
     reply = (TokenDTO) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
    }catch (JAXBException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return reply.getToken();
}
```

Is this the right way? Can I do it a different way?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Keep in mind that most web frameworks or HTTP client libraries would have builtin JSON functions